# Spark Streaming StackOverflow with updateStateByKey

Tags: apache-spark, window, spark-streaming

In my use case, I need to maintain historical data for a key. For this, I am using updateStateByKey in which state is maintained as mutable scala collection(ArrayBuffer). Each element in ArrayBuffer is an incoming record. Spark version is 1.6

As the number of elements(records) increases in the ArrayBuffer for a key I am getting following StackOverflow error.

```
18/03/28 07:31:55 ERROR scheduler.JobScheduler: Error running job streaming job 1459150304000 ms.2 
java.lang.StackOverflowError 
        at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.stripSuffix(StringOps.scala:31) 
        at org.apache.spark.Logging$class.logName(Logging.scala:44) 
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.logName(RDD.scala:74) 
        at org.apache.spark.Logging$class.log(Logging.scala:51) 
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.log(RDD.scala:74) 
        at org.apache.spark.Logging$class.logDebug(Logging.scala:62) 
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.logDebug(RDD.scala:74) 
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.CoGroupedRDD$$anonfun$getDependencies$1.apply(CoGroupedRDD.scala:104) 
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.CoGroupedRDD$$anonfun$getDependencies$1.apply(CoGroupedRDD.scala:99) 
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244) 
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244) 
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318) 
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244) 
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105) 
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.CoGroupedRDD.getDependencies(CoGroupedRDD.scala:99) 
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$dependencies$2.apply(RDD.scala:226) 
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$dependencies$2.apply(RDD.scala:224) 
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120) 
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.dependencies(RDD.scala:224) 
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.CoGroupedRDD$$anonfun$getPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$mcVI$sp$1.apply(CoGroupedRDD.scala:117) 
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.CoGroupedRDD$$anonfun$getPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$mcVI$sp$1.apply(CoGroupedRDD.scala:115) 
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244) 
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244) 
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318) 
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244) 
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105) 
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.CoGroupedRDD$$anonfun$getPartitions$1.apply$mcVI$sp(CoGroupedRDD.scala:115) 
        at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:141) 
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.CoGroupedRDD.getPartitions(CoGroupedRDD.scala:113) 
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239) 
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237) 
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120) 
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237) 
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35) 
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239) 
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237) 
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120) 
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237) 
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35) 
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239) 
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237) 
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120) 
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237) 
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.CoGroupedRDD$$anonfun$getPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$mcVI$sp$1.apply(CoGroupedRDD.scala:121) 
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.CoGroupedRDD$$anonfun$getPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$mcVI$sp$1.apply(CoGroupedRDD.scala:115) 
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
```

Following is the code snippet

```
def updateState(rows: Seq[ArrayBuffer[Row]], state: Option[ArrayBuffer[Row]]) = { 

      val prevState = state.getOrElse[ArrayBuffer[Row]](ArrayBuffer[Row]()) 

      val newState = ArrayBuffer.empty[Row] 
      newState ++= prevState 
      for (r <- rows) { 
        newState += r(0) 
      } 
      Some(newState) 
    } 

    val pairedFaultStream = getPairedStream(faultStream, sqlContext) 
    val workingStream = pairedFaultStream.updateStateByKey[ArrayBuffer[Row]](updateState _).map(_._2)
```

I have tried following approaches

1. Truncating lineage by caching and checkpointing rdd of
   workingStream.
2. Using kryo serialization.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: I would avoid using `updateStateByKey` unless you need to touch every key on every batch. Consider using `mapWithState` instead.

Comment: yes, I need to use every key on each batch.

Comment: What is your batch duration? How often do you checkpoint?